# Plugin eclipse subversive genera error y eclipse no arranca

Tags: java, eclipse, subversion

He instalado la última versión de eclipse (Oxygen) y tengo problemas para instalar el plugin subversive desde el marketplace.

Tras instalar este, me aparece un error y si cierro eclipse, después no arranca.

He probado a eliminar la carpeta .metadatos y sigue sin arrancar. Al parecer el plugin no se instala correctamente, el conector no funciona y al reiniciar, eclipse no puede arrancar.

Estoy pensando en cambiar de plugin aunque tampoco hay mucho donde elegir y este me funcionaba bien con la versión Neon.

Adjunto error:

> ```
> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
> session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, 
> phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
> Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/Program%20Files/eclipse/.
> C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.jboss.netty_3.2.4.Final-201112281337.jar 
> (Access is denied)
> ```

Comment: Hola Alex, bienvenido a [es.so]. Lee el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio y también [ask] para aprender a hacer preguntas de calidad. Tu pregunta no es valida porque entra en la categoria de *Error no reproducible*. Te sugiero que muestres el error para poder acotar el problema. Un saludo

Comment: Te sugiero que digas las versiones para que te puedan ayudar mejor.

Comment: Pon el mensaje de Error como texto en vez de Imagen. será mas facil de leer desde cualquier dispositivo y tardará menos en cargar si usas una red movil (además que si el enlace de la imagen se rompe, la pregunta pierde sentido)

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer, el plugin subversive del marketplace de eclipse no se instala correctamente en la versión Oxygen de eclipse y es necesario desinstalarlo para volverlo a instalar.

Además de esto, si instalas eclipse directamente en C:, al parecer se obtienen problemas de escritura y, por tanto, hay que utilizar otra ruta.

Por otro lado, subclipse no me ha funcionado correctamente y eclipse me ha remitido un mensaje que decía que la versión no es compatible.

Respecto a la imposibilidad de arrancar eclipse cuando esto pasa, la única opción que me ha funcionado ha sido eliminar el workspace y las carpetas de instalación de eclipse situadas en la carpeta de usuario y volver a instalar de nuevo la versión de eclipse.

Comment: Me alegra que fueras capaz de solucionarlo. Por favor, haz lo que te comento en el ultimo comentario de tu pregunta. Pasadas 48h podrás marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada. Un saludo

Comment: Hecho. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: pero no quites el error, dejalo en formato de texto. sin el error, la pregutna pierde sentido. quien la vea en un futuro no sabrá si tu respuesta le vale al no saber si vuestro error era el mismo

Comment: Perdona, modificado...